# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement text-editor

Tags: python, heroku

Whenever I try to deploy my GitHub branch using Heroku, I get the following error message:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement text-editor (from os-sys->-r /tmp/build_56b4de0b_/requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for text-editor (from os-sys->-r /tmp/build_56b4de0b_/requirements.txt (line 3))`

EDIT: my requirements.txt

```
discord.py
requests
os-sys
asyncio
youtube_dl
```

SOLUTION:

Managed to fix it by removing os-sys from my requirements.txt file

Comment: Add your requirements.txt at least.

Comment: are you sure the package is `text-editor` and not `texteditor`?

Comment: added requirements.txt

Comment: There is no text-editor on that requirements.txt file. Is that the *same* file you pushed to Heroku?

Comment: that's the same file. Should I add text-editor to it?

Comment: It looks like `os-sys` has `text-editor` as a requirement, see [here](https://github.com/Matthijs990/os-sys-github/blob/master/setup.py#L275). However, there seems to be no such package on pypi.

Comment: I am also facing this issue anyone has any idea how to resolve it without removing os-sys module